# Programmatically uninstall/ remove/ disable provisioning profile

Tags: ios

I would like to find a way to programmatically uninstall/ remove/ disable a configuration profile on ios iphone/ipad...

I have an enterprise distribution license. The app is for in-house distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have seen that will facilitate removal of provisioning profiles on iOS is through the use of an MDM application.  Here is a link with more information:

http://www.enterpriseios.com/story/2013/01/28/Enterprise_In_House_Certificate_Life_Extended#comment-7798